# Nitrous.io google_drive gem "Authentication failed" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-drive-api, nitrousio, learn-ruby-on-rails

I am trying to utilize the google_drive gem in a Rails app and am getting the following error:

"Authentication failed for [my_email_address]@gmail.com: Response code 403 for post https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin: Error=BadAuthentication Info=InvalidSecondFactor"

Google is preventing access (I keep getting security warnings via email from Google: "Google Account: sign-in attempt blocked"), and am looking for a way to get around this error.

Someone suggested I enabled two-step verification in my gmail account to ultimately retrieve an "application-specific password." I entered the application-specific password in place of my normal gmail password but Google, I believe, is still denying my application access to my gmail account.

Any idea how to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

Solution...

Disable two-step verification.

Go here: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Enable "Less secure apps"

Run app again with usual password.